# How can I do template matching in opencv with colour?

Tags: numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I have been trying to use opencv's template matching function to match templates within images. However, when the images are dark brown and dark green, the template matching does not work so well. I am pretty sure it is the grey scale conversion that is responsible for this because in greyscale it looks very similar.

However from what I see, cv2.matchtemplate() only takes in grey scale images. How can I do coloured template matching? Should I seperate the RGB image into 3 images: one red, one green, one blue and treat each one as gray scale images and apply matchtemplate then sum the similarity rating for each pixel position? Is that the way to do it? Or is there a different function or a parameter value I can use to make matchtemplate work for coloured images?

Comment: Your own suggestion seems good enough to be executed. You can sum them all up or multiply them. Summing them would mean the object needs to satisfy any of the RGB condition and multiplying them would mean the object needs to satisfy all of RGB conditions

Comment: That is actually a very useful point.

Comment: Just to piggy back off the suggestion above, part of the reason it probably isn't implemented in the library is because there are different measurements of "distance" between colors depending on what colorspace you're in---if it did three channel images, it'd probably just sum them or the L2 norm or something, but that's not a great distance metric for colors. So, it's up to the implementer depending on their colorspace. But you can definitely try summing, taking the sqrt of the sum of squares, etc. All should work decently well.

Comment: That's a very good point, it is quite easy to implement for the user.

Comment: colorMatchtemplate : https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d17/group__ximgproc__filters.html#ga370f180e4a52231ba218adbb4a65a9ca and an example here https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/ximgproc/samples/color_match_template.cpp

Answer (score 1):

You may try this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

threshold = 0.8

##Read Main and Needle Image
imageMainRGB = cv2.imread(main/Image/Path/main.png)
imageNeedleRGB = cv2.imread(needle/Image/Path/needle.png)

##Split Both into each R, G, B Channel
imageMainR, imageMainG, imageMainB = cv2.split(imageMainRGB)
imageNeedleR, imageNeedleG, imageNeedleB = cv2.split(imageNeedleRGB)

##Matching each channel
resultB = cv2.matchTemplate(imageMainR, imageNeedleR, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
resultG = cv2.matchTemplate(imageMainG, imageNeedleG, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
resultR = cv2.matchTemplate(imageMainB, imageNeedleB, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)

##Add together to get the total score
result = resultB + resultG + resultR
loc = np.where(result >= 3 * threshold)
print("loc: ", loc)
```

The Image I tested with are:

main.png

[image: main.png]

needle.png

[image: needle.png]

result.png

[image: result.png]

Remark: This code may not function in some photos, where a user may need to modify it further to enhance it.

Note: This image was getting from pexels.com which is free copyright. If you have any issues with the image copyright and want to take down this image, welcome to contact me. Thanks.